# MySQL Error? Where the syntax mistake?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-delete

Tried thus query with "SELECT *" instead of "DELETE FROM" and it worked perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM  `80dage_garmin_track` t1 WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT 1 
FROM  `80dage_garmin_track` t2
WHERE t1.Length = t2.Length
AND t1.Time = t2.Time
AND t1.idgarmin_track > t2.idgarmin_track
)
```

**MySQL Error:**
.#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server    version for the right syntax to use    near 't1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from     80dage_garmin_track` t2 WHERE t1.Le'    at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not allow all kinds of sub selects in the WHERE clause of DELETE, see [this thread](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2920). Yours may (or may not) be fine, if you drop the table alias (t1), which is also not allowed for DELETE.

Comment: +1 for... drop the table alias (t1), which is also not allowed for DELETE

Comment: I did a SELECT of the query and seleced all rows in phpmyadmin and deleted them. Worked out well.